# All Excel Formulas Updating at Once

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use to use the following formula in an excel document: =IF(C2="","",NOW()). I'm just trynig to capture the time that a cell is populated. The problem I am running into is that everytime one formula updates, they all update.

For example, if I have the two formuals:

```
=IF(C2="","",NOW())
=IF(C3="","",NOW())
```

If I update C3, the formula that relates to C2 also upates. So my times are always identical to the last updated cell. I can't get them to update when only there dependent cells update.

One other thing of note, this spreadsheet is being used in MS Teams, so macros are not an option.

Is there a setting I have incorrect potentially? Or a work around?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Formulas are live and NOW is volatile, which means it will calculate any time Excel calculates.  You will need to manually put in the date time if vba is not an option.

Comment: That is kind of the conclusion I was coming to, but was hoping someone had a work around. I tried doing the following: if(d2<>"", ,IF(C2="","",NOW())), where d2 is the cell that the formula is in. I thought this might keep the inner formula from updating if the cell was already populated. Excel didn't like the formula referencing its own cell.

Comment: Older versions used to allow the ability to allow circular references and you could refer to itself.  But that has always been hacky and relies on the user changing the settings to allow it each time they open the document.  Newer version are a lot more finiky about the use of circular references.  And I believe that the online app does not allow them at all.

Comment: also the formula would have been: `=if(d2<>"",d2 ,IF(C2="","",NOW()))`

Comment: I use a shortcut to enter the time cmnd+;

Comment: Would it be helpful to what you are trying to do to be able to review the changes made in the spreadsheet? See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-changes-that-were-made-in-a-workbook-978ceea7-bbf6-4337-bca7-22e7cc9892e8)

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks for the feedback. Looks like for now inputs will have to be manual

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Office Scripts? They work a lot like macros in VBA, but they are for Excel Online.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is expected since `=NEW()` always returns the current  time, and you have no control of when a sheet might recalculate.

The best way to handle this situation is to have a macro that runs when the worksheet updates and it manually writes *a value* into the desired cell from the current time.

For example if the values to be tracked are in column "C" (the 3rd column) then the code below will write the current time of the adjacent cell (one column over) every time that value changes.

Place the code below under the worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 3 Then
    
        If IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, 1)) Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
        End If
    
    End If

End Sub
```

[image: scr1]

[image: scr2]

The code above checks to see if a timestamp is already filled before setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(CELL("row")=ROW(C2), NOW(), C2)
```

Drag down your C column as needed.

NOTE: You'll need to enable iterative calculations for formulas (Options -> Formulas).